# Can you say "added things" in one word?

Tags: word-request

I'm creating a folder in my computer where I will add modifications that I will make to a software I'm writing. The point is that I will only put changes to a specific feature of my software into it and only changes that will add new functionalities. I'm looking for a concise folder name for this.

I would give the folder a name similar to <feature-name>_<added-things>, but I would like to use one single word instead of "added things".

Comment: The first word that came to my mind is "updates", but 'tis a bit broad (contextual usage). Hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additions / Add-ons

Literally means "things that have been added". This may fit quite well, however it only includes things that have been added, and not changes to previous software. There are some software terms you can use for new material:

> Patches

These are bug fixes and maintenance. (Changes to already existing code)

> Updates

A general word for new software. This includes patches as well as new content and features)

Comment: I think that "additions" is the good one, as I want to emphasize the sense of "adding". Thank you.